# How to suppress this - qglobal.h:320:6: warning: #warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, osx-lion

I am encountering the following warning

```
/path/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:320:6:
warning: #warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
```

Here is qglobal.h

```
 301 #ifdef Q_OS_DARWIN
 302 #  ifdef MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
 303 #    undef MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
 304 #  endif
 305 #  define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4
 306 #  include <AvailabilityMacros.h>
 307 #  if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3)
 308 #     define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3 MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_2 + 1
 309 #  endif
 310 #  if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4)
 311 #       define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4 MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3 + 1
 312 #  endif
 313 #  if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5)
 314 #       define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5 MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4 + 1
 315 #  endif
 316 #  if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6)
 317 #       define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5 + 1
 318 #  endif
 319 #  if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6)
 320 #    warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
 321 #  endif
 322 #endif
```

I am on 10.7 and hence the warning. But how do I suppress it?

Also are there any serious consequences? My program is otherwise getting compiled fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not download the latest Qt installer from:

http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

I see a "Mac OS X 10.6 or later (64-bit)" download right there on that page.

Comment: Just because you downloaded Qt from there doesn't mean you have the latest version. The current version of Qt is 4.8.2 whereas the number in the path you put up there is - I believe - 4.7.4 (e.g. "`/path/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/**474**/gcc`").

Answer (score 1):

Just comment these three lines out:

```
 319 // #  if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6)
 320 // #    warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
 321 // #  endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael Dautermann that you should install the new version, but here's another solution:
change this line:

```
   #  if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 + 1)
```

If that doesn't work, try  adding 2 instead of 1.